# Using pumping lemma

Tags: proof-verification, computer-science, regular-language, pumping-lemma

I'm trying to prove that the language $\mathcal L = \{w \in \{0,1\}^* ∣ w \leq w′ \text{ where }w′ \text{ is any rotation of }w\}$ is not a regular language.

**Note: The inequality is with respect to lexicographic order. And if $w=xy$, then $yx$ is a rotation of $w$.**

I was thinking of using the string $s = 0^{P}1$ with $P$ being the pumping length, but I can't figure out how to pump this in a way to show a contradiction. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If $p$ is the pumping length, start with $s=0^p10^p1$ and pump *down*.

Comment: When you say pump down, do you mean take the divided string's pumpable portion and go from something like say 5, down to 4, 3, etc?

Comment: @Vimzy: The pumping lemma says that $s$ decomposes as $xyz$, where $|xy|\le p$, $|y|\ge 1$, and $xy^kz\in L$ for each $k\ge 0$. The original $s$ has $k=1$; pumping down is setting $k=0$.

Comment: But s=0p10p1 wouldn't even be a part of the language L? On certain rotations, 0p10p1 is greater than the rotation?

Comment: @Vimzy: $0^p10^p1$ is in $L$: no rotation has more than $p$ leading zeroes.

Comment: I think I may just be misunderstanding the lexicographic condition here, but isn't 0101 when rotated to 0011 come out to 0101>0011? I think I may have a misunderstanding here?

Comment: @Vimzy: $0101$ can’t be rotated to $0011$; its rotations are $1010$ and itself. You get $1010$ if you split it $0\mid 101$ or $010\mid 1$, and you get $0101$ if you split it in the middle. (In other words, your understanding of lexicographic order is probably fine; it’s rotation that you’re misunderstanding.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35530/discussion-between-vimzy-and-brian-m-scott).